# How to fix 'tuple index out of range' error on sklearn fit_transform?

Tags: scikit-learn, tuples

I have a one dimensional tuple with data that I have read from a .csv file. I then initialize a One Hot Encoder class with the code below. However, I keep getting an error

I have tried converting the tuple to a 2D Tuple, but it hasn't worked.

```py
output_data = dataset.iloc[:,9].values

#Encoding the categorical output data (There is no categorical input data)

one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
output_data = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(output_data).toarray()
```

I keep getting an error of "IndexError: tuple index out of range"

Comment: Can you share your `dataset`? Just enough to get a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brother everything is perfect but you need to reshape your dataset.

By adding that code of line

> output_data = temp.reshape(-1, 1)

```
output_data = dataset.iloc[:,9].values

#Encoding the categorical output data (There is no categorical input data)
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])

#Reshape dataset before apply fit_transform function
output_data = temp.reshape(-1, 1)
output_data = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(output_data).toarray()
```

Comment: it says 'temp' is not defined?

Answer (score 1):

use get_dummies it works for 1D

```
import numpy as np
y = pd.get_dummies(y)
```

Remember to transform y back to array:

```
y = np.array(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `output_data` is returned as the type of `pandas.frame.Series` so it must be reshaped or converted to `pandas.frame.DataFrame`

```
output_data = DataFrame(output_data)
output_data = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(output_data).toarray() # don't forget toarray() here
```